# How can I put new line in between function arguments

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I have a function that has plently of arguments.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.2pt}
\begin{table}[ht]
    $Z(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, X, Y, Z) = 100 * 100 - f(A, B)$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

output:

`Z(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, X, Y, Z) = 100 * 100 - f(A, B)`

---

Since I am using two-columns the equation takes wide space.
Instead is it possible put new line in between the function arguments, simple exampls as follows:

```
   A, B, C,
   D, E, F,
Z (F, H, I,) = 100 * 100 - f(A, B)
   J, K, L,
   X, Y, Z
```

Please note that, I am not sure is this a correct way to represent since it may look like since matrix as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an array or similar.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

    $Z\left(\begin{array}{c@{\ }c@{\ }c}
                      A, &B, &C,\\
                      D, &E, &F,\\
                      G, &H, &I,\\
                      J, &K, &L,\\
                      X, &Y, &Z 
            \end{array}\right) = 100 * 100 - f(A, B)$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: argument array]

EDIT: Or if you want it in an equation environment, per the comment below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    Z\left(\begin{array}{c@{\ }c@{\ }c}
                      A, &B, &C,\\
                      D, &E, &F,\\
                      G, &H, &I,\\
                      J, &K, &L,\\
                      X, &Y, &Z 
            \end{array}\right) = 100 * 100 - f(A, B)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can we use equation instead of table?

Comment: Do you mean use an equation environment rather than a table environment? Sure. I only put it inside a table environment because that's what your original code did. Remove the `$`s though, since equations put things in math mode. I'll put code for that in the answer.